# Opening and reading files in C

Tags: c, fopen

im trying to open a file and i want to safe the first line into an char array. When i run the program, the window pop ups and i get an error message, "*.exe stopped Working". I don't get an specific error Code or an Warning before i compile it.

In the console there is following: "Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
"
Im using CodeBlocks as an Distribution.

Here is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[60];
    FILE* ptr = fopen("tipps.txt", "r");
    fgets(buffer, 60, ptr);
    for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
        printf("%s", buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The first line of "tipps.txt" is:

```
   0145874 1 -----------X---X----X-------------X--X-X---------
```

Comment: `printf("%s", buffer[i]);`  -> `printf("%c", buffer[i]);`. See format specifiers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: `%s` is for printing whole strings.  Looks like you're trying to print individual characters.  Use `%c` for that.

Comment: Also, check that `ptr != NULL` before attempting to read from it. That could also cause an earlier segmentation fault. And `for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)` is going to cause undefined behavior, instead try `for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)` or `for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\n'; i++)`. Or simply, `puts(buffer)`.

Comment: These days, good compilers warn you when you have mismatched printf format specifiers.  Somewhat surprised yours didn't.  You might want to look into upping the warning level.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for errors in order to be able to tell why the program didn't do what you expected it to do, if it stills doesn't do what you expected it to do then you check your logic, and if you still can't find out you can then ask on Stack Overflow.

The minimal error checking for your code is

```
char buffer[60];
FILE *file;

file = fopen("tipps.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error, cannot open `tipps.txt'\n");
    return -1;
}

// Check that `fgets()' did read something, it could fail
// for instance at EOF.
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL) {
    // Iterate through the characters until we find
    // the null terminator.
    for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        fputc(buffer[i], stdout);
    }
}
```

Also, read the documentation for each function thoroughly. For instance this [printf()](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#printf). At that link you can find others like `fgets()`, and `fputc()` and `fopen()`.

Note that everything is important, what the parameters mean and what the return value, if any, means. When you feel that you really understand the function then start using it in your code.